# How to add static pages in the Magento 2 search result?

Tags: magento2, search, static-content

I'm using a Magento 2.4 and in my project I have many static pages that I would like to be part of my search results.

[image: Magento 2 search]

How could I add Magento 2 static pages in my search results?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in search template:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$queryText = $objectManager->create('Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory')->get()->getQueryText();
$pageCollection=$objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Model\Page')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
->addFieldToFilter(
  array('title','content'),
  array(array('like'=>'%'.$queryText.'%'), 
  array('like'=>'%'.$queryText.'%')));
```